# Getting 500 Error when loading "send email" page

Tags: php, html-email

Sp I am trying to send out an email, the code worked fine until I switched over to html email from a standard email.

It is live here: http://kenthomes.net/Amelia-Cove

Click "Share this plan".

My code is:

```
    $person = $_POST["name"];

    //Where will you be pulling emails from?
    $emailDB = "emailAddresses";
    $type = $_POST["type"];

    //Get Share URL that is misformatted.
    $waybefore = $_GET["share"];
    $before = str_replace("*", "?", $waybefore);
    $shareMe = str_replace("!", "=", $before);

    $id = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; 
    $id = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; 
    //Where do you want a copy of this email to go to? (or null)
    $copyDB = "";

    if($_GET["com"])
    {
        $prettyType = "Community";
    }
    else if($_GET["inv"])
    {
        $prettyType = "Move-In Ready Home";
    }
    else if($_GET["mod"])
    {
        $prettyType = "Model Home";
    }

    $_POST["date"] = date("Y-m-d");

    $Emails = new Controller($emailDB, null, null, true);

    $ed = $Emails->getData();

    //
    // The good stuff
    //

    $emailTo = $_POST["email"];
    $subject = "Kent Homes - " . $person . " would like to share a " . ucwords(strtolower($_GET['type'])) . " with you!";

    $out = '<html><body>';
    $out .= $person . " thought you would like this " . $prettyType . " by Kent Homes.  Click the link to view: http://kenthomes.net" . $shareMe . "</br></br>";
    $out .= "Additional Message from " . $person . "</br>";
    $out .= $_POST['msg'];
    $out .= '</body></html>';

    $headers = "From: " . $person "<noreply@kenthomes.com>\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: <noreply@kenthomes.com\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion()."\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

    //
    // Send 'er off!
    //

    mail($emailTo, $subject, $out, $headers);

    if($toEmail) {
        mail($emailTo, $subject, $out, $headers);
    }

    echo "<p>This " . ucwords(strtolower($_GET['type'])) . " has been sent to " . $_POST["email"] . ".</p>";
    unset($_POST["id"]);
```

I am getting error:

```
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.
```

This is what the functioning code looks like before the html mail stuff:

```
            $Captcha = new MCaptcha();
                if($_POST["submitit"])
                {
                    $answer = $Captcha->checkAnswer();
                    if($answer)
                    {
                        $person = $_POST["name"];
                        $emailTo = $_POST["email"];
                        $subject = "Kent Homes - " . $person . " would like to share a " . ucwords(strtolower($_GET['type'])) . " with you!";

                        //Where will you be pulling emails from?
                        $emailDB = "emailAddresses";
                        $type = $_POST["type"];

                        //Get Share URL that is misformatted.
                        $waybefore = $_GET["share"];
                        $before = str_replace("*", "?", $waybefore);
                        $shareMe = str_replace("!", "=", $before);

                        $id = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; 
                        $id = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; 
                        //Where do you want a copy of this email to go to? (or null)
                        $copyDB = "";

                        if($_GET["com"])
                        {
                            $prettyType = "Community";
                        }
                        else if($_GET["inv"])
                        {
                            $prettyType = "Move-In Ready Home";
                        }
                        else if($_GET["mod"])
                        {
                            $prettyType = "Model Home";
                        }

                        $out = $person . " thought you would like this " . $prettyType . " by Kent Homes.  Click the link to view: http://kenthomes.net" . $shareMe . " ";

                        $_POST["date"] = date("Y-m-d");

                        $Emails = new Controller($emailDB, null, null, true);

                        $ed = $Emails->getData();

                        mail($emailTo, $subject, $out, $headers);

                        if($toEmail) {
                            mail($emailTo, $subject, $out, $headers);
                        }

                        echo "<p>This " . ucwords(strtolower($_GET['type'])) . " has been sent to " . $_POST["email"] . ".</p>";
                        unset($_POST["id"]);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: what does your `error_log` say?  where is `$toEmail` set for your `if($toEmail) {` check? Looks like the same `mail()` call twice.

Comment: Yeah, for some reason, it wasn't emailing out when I removed that if statement, odd, I know.

Comment: that's probably more at the root of your issue.

Comment: Still not working at http://kenthomes.net/Amelia-Cove (exact file is http://kenthomes.net/shareplan.php)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problems with the code that would cause a 500. Unseen items that could cause a 500:

1. Is 'Controller' included and defined?
2. Does anything happen in the constructing of a Controller that would cause a 500?
3. Is there a syntax error in the code you removed to make this snippet?

To start with, I would check your apache logs. In Ubuntu, they're typically in /var/log/apache2/error.log. If nothing prints in your error log, then it's possible you're running out of memory or time. I doubt this is the case, but if it is, then these will help:

ini_set('memory_limit', '1G');
set_time_limit(3600);

They will help you diagnose, but you want to configure your runtime for your use case.

If something does print in your error log, investigate it - it's probably the issue.

If none of those help, try dying in the middle of the script to see how far it gets. As soon as you get to the offending piece of code, it will die on its own without printing out the die message.

die("got here");

Comment: Yeah. I put a die() at a lot of different places in the code, no dice. I am updating my code above to include the code that actually works (before i went to html)

Answer (score 0):

Syntax Error at:

```
$out .= "Additional Message from " $person . "</br>";
```

This should be:

```
$out .= "Additional Message from " . $person . "</br>";
```

Comment: Heh, yeah that's what I meant... not $out.

Where is my mind today.